# How can I page up to a certain amount of items?

Tags: java, micronaut

I do the pagination in a repository, bringing in all the items and stop the search when the items have all been brought in.

```
List<MyList> myList = new ArrayList<>();
var page = Pageable.from(0, 500);
Page<MyList> myListPage;
do {
      myListPage = repository.findByStatus(STATUS, page);
      var result = myListPage();
      myList(result);
      page = page.next();
 } while (!myListPage.isEmpty());
```

But now I want to page, bring the items, only up to a specific quantity, for example 1000 items.

When I have brought 1000 items, I stop the search.

How can I do this ?

I have a `PageableRepository` thats `extends` a `CruRepository`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Keep It Simple, Stupid" ©Kelly Johnson

If you need 1000 elements then why don't you set 1000 as page size?
At first glance, I see no reason not to set 1000 as the page size.

```
Pageable pageRequest = PageRequest.of(0, 1000);
Page<YourEntity> results = repository.findAllByStatus(STATUS, pageRequest);
```

---

Updated:
You can run a count query to get the total number of records. Then you can calculate how many requests you need to make according to page size and offset.

```
long allRecordsNumberWithGivenStatus = repository.countByStatus(status);
```

or

```
long allRecordsNumberWithGivenStatus = repository.countEnityByStatus(status);
```

I don't remember the syntax.

Comment: I need 1000 elements in total. That is, with the page size at 100... I would have 10 pages, with 100 elements each. This is an example...

Comment: I can't bring all elements at once

Comment: You can run a count query to get the total number of records. Then you can calculate how many requests you need to make according to page size and offset.

Comment: Added to my answer how to count records. The rest is just math.